# Convergence of the Ratio of Expected Values

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I would like some help proving the following result. Thanks for any help in advance.

> Let ($x_{n}), n \geq 1$ be a sequence of $\ell_{p}$ random variables for some $p$ in (1, $\infty$) and suppose that
>
> (1) $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $E|x_{n}|^{p} = \infty$
>
> and
>
> (2) $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $P(|x_{n}| > A) = 0$ for some $0 < A < \infty$.
>
> Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $(E|x_{n}|)^{p} /E|x_{n}|^{p} = 0$

My initial thought was to separate out $E|x_{n}|$ into the expected value of $|x_{n}|$ multiplied by the indicator of $[|x_{n}| > A]$ plus the expected value of $|x_{n}|$ multiplied by the indicator of $[|x_{n}| \leq A]$, and then attempt to apply Holder's inequality on the former term in the sum, but I didn't get anywhere with this technique.

Comment: You should apply Holder on the first term (not the latter which anyhow stays bounded).

Comment: I made a mistake in the above description. I applied Holder to the first term. I will edit this in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 
$$ \int |x_n| \; 1_{|x_n|>A} \leq  \|x_n\|_p\ \  \|1_{|x_n|>A}\|_q = \|x_n\|_p \ \ P(|x_n|>A)^{1/q}$$
from which:
$$ \|x_n\|_1 \leq A + \int |x_n| \; 1_{|x_n|>A} \leq A + \| x_n\|_p P(|x_n|>A)^{p/q}.$$
As $\|x_n\|_p\rightarrow \infty$ and $P(|x_n|>A)\rightarrow 0$ we conclude that
$$ \frac{\|x_n\|_1}{\|x_n\|_p} \leq  \frac{A}{\| x_n\|_p }+P(|x_n|>A)^{p/q}\rightarrow 0$$

Comment: Isn't there an issue here with the fact that I have to deal with $||x_{n}||_{1}$ being raised to the $p$ power?

Comment: No, not really  since $E(|x_n|)^p / E(|x_n|^p) = (\|x_n\|_1/\|x_n\|_p)^p$ (if this is related to your worry?)